# Delete page numbers from mdpi article

Tags: numbering, pdfpages, page, mdpi

I am trying to insert an mdpi published article of mine to my PhD thesis using the command \includepdf using pagecommand = {}. However, this way both document numbering and article numbering are included. As I want to remove article page numbering, I am using command "\pagenumbering{gobble}". However, as the article has page number format like "page-of-total pages" eg 1 of 15, 2 of 15 etc... this way I am left with "of".

Any idea how I can remove this?

Edit: I am providing the preamble, where the page information should be contained, probably hidden within mdpi class file.

```
\documentclass[entropy,article,submit,moreauthors,pdftex]{Definitions/mdpi} 
%---------
% article
%---------
% The default type of manuscript is "article", but can be replaced by: 
% abstract, addendum, article, book, bookreview, briefreport, casereport, comment, commentary, communication, conferenceproceedings, correction, conferencereport, entry, expressionofconcern, extendedabstract, datadescriptor, editorial, essay, erratum, hypothesis, interestingimage, obituary, opinion, projectreport, reply, retraction, review, perspective, protocol, shortnote, studyprotocol, systematicreview, supfile, technicalnote, viewpoint, guidelines, registeredreport, tutorial
% supfile = supplementary materials

%----------
% submit
%----------
% The class option "submit" will be changed to "accept" by the Editorial Office when the paper is accepted. This will only make changes to the frontpage (e.g., the logo of the journal will get visible), the headings, and the copyright information. Also, line numbering will be removed. Journal info and pagination for accepted papers will also be assigned by the Editorial Office.

%------------------
% moreauthors
%------------------
% If there is only one author the class option oneauthor should be used. Otherwise use the class option moreauthors.

%---------
% pdftex
%---------
% The option pdftex is for use with pdfLaTeX. If eps figures are used, remove the option pdftex and use LaTeX and dvi2pdf.

%=================================================================
% MDPI internal commands
\firstpage{1} 
\makeatletter 
\setcounter{page}{\@firstpage} 
\makeatother
\pubvolume{1}
\issuenum{1}
\articlenumber{0}
\pubyear{2022}
\copyrightyear{2022}
%\externaleditor{Academic Editor: Firstname Lastname}
\datereceived{} 
\dateaccepted{} 
\datepublished{} 
%\datecorrected{} % Corrected papers include a "Corrected: XXX" date in the original paper.
%\dateretracted{} % Corrected papers include a "Retracted: XXX" date in the original paper.
\hreflink{https://doi.org/} % If needed use \linebreak
%\doinum{}
%------------------------------------------------------------------
% The following line should be uncommented if the LaTeX file is uploaded to arXiv.org
%\pdfoutput=1

\graphicspath{{figures/}}



%=================================================================
% Add packages and commands here. The following packages are loaded in our class file: fontenc, inputenc, calc, indentfirst, fancyhdr, graphicx, epstopdf, lastpage, ifthen, lineno, float, amsmath, setspace, enumitem, mathpazo, booktabs, titlesec, etoolbox, tabto, xcolor, soul, multirow, microtype, tikz, totcount, changepage, attrib, upgreek, cleveref, amsthm, hyphenat, natbib, hyperref, footmisc, url, geometry, newfloat, caption   

%\usepackage{graphics} % for pdf, bitmapped graphics files
%\usepackage{epsfig} % for postscript graphics files
%\usepackage{mathptmx} % assumes new font selection scheme installed
%\usepackage{times} % assumes new font selection scheme installed
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[english]{babel} % for proper hyphenation patterns
%\usepackage [super]{nth}


%=================================================================
%% Please use the following mathematics environments: Theorem, Lemma, Corollary, Proposition, Characterization, Property, Problem, Example, ExamplesandDefinitions, Hypothesis, Remark, Definition, Notation, Assumption
%% For proofs, please use the proof environment (the amsthm package is loaded by the MDPI class).

%=================================================================
% Full title of the paper (Capitalized)
```

and then the document starts with no page numbering setup

Edit2:

Thanks a lot to everyone! I have been able to solve it by modifying the mdpi.cls file, where by default the article style was accompanied with the pagenumbering style as "1 of 15" etc...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Without seeing the code of the document (document class, packages), it's hard to know for sure, but the usual way of suppressing page numbers is with `\pagestyle{empty}` (for the default) and `\thispagestyle{empty}` (for special pages). If that doesn't work, it would be best to see the relevant code as a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). An alternative might be to use the trim and clip options to `\includepdf` to cut them off when they're inserted.

Comment: Another option could be to cover it with a `\rule` the same colour as the page.

Comment: Is simply recompiling (or, come thing of it, editing/modifying) the included .pdf (without page numbers, obviously) not an option? Or could it be cropped?

Comment: As others have mentioned the page numbers are a build in feature of the PDF you want to include. This can be done via tikz and the `pagecommand` option for `\includepdf`. For example `\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand=\ninja]{article.pdf}` where `\ninja` is a macro containing a `tikzpicture` with options `overlay,remember picture` and in it you place a white box over the appropriate area. We've used this approach for many PhD dissertations with great success.

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone. I have been able to solve this and edited my question.